# Eliminar datos repetidos oracle

Tags: oracle

Supongamos que tengo esta tabla "Producto"

```
id number
categoria
nombre varchar
precio number
```

Necesito hacer una consulta en oracle que me elimine los datos duplicados que coincidan el nombre y precio, ¿es posible con una consulta sin usar un procedimiento?

Comment: Y que criterio usarías para eliminar los duplicados? Es decir tienes dos productos cuyo precio y nombre es el mismo, cual de los dos eliminas?

Comment: el que tengo id menor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La forma más optima es :

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE rowid not in (SELECT MIN(rowid) 
FROM table  GROUP BY "nombre", "precio" );
```

Answer (score 0):

Podrías hacer lo siguiente:

```
select  min(id) id,
    nombre,
    precio
    from productos p
    left join (select   nombre, precio, count(1)
                from productos
                group by nombre, precio
                having count(1) > 1
    ) dup
        on dup.nombre = p.nombre
        and dup.precio = p.precio
    group by 
      nombre,
      precio
```

El `select` más interno traería los `precios` y `nombres` que estuvieran duplicados, luego hacemos `join` con los productos para tener los `id` de los duplicados, y en el último `select`, agrupamos y obtenemos el menor `id` por cada `nombre` y `precio`. Ese entiendo debería ser el `id` a eliminar (`delete productos where id in (...)`). Lógicamente al hacerlo así no estaríamos contemplando si por ejemplo hay más de dos duplicados, en ese caso podríamos quedarnos con el `max(id)` que sería el que debiera "sobrevivir" y eliminar los otros que coincidan en `nombre` y `precio` y no tenga dicho `ìd`

Comment: hay alguna forma mas simple? he puesto solo 2 campos pero realmente seran 30

Comment: @sirdaiz: al menos yo, no me imagino otra forma.

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta, encontre otra forma, un saludo